# 500 /signalr/negotiate for deployed app in Azure

Tags: azure, signalr

When deployed to Azure SignalR doens't work  works on localhost  but doesn't work when deployed to Azure

It responds with a 500 internal server error response when doing the signalr/negotiate request.

Navigating manually to the negotiate url, I got a more detailed error explanation. 
'*CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful...*'

Everything works fine locally, using IISExpress.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution. This worked for me without making any code changes:

Azure WebApps is configured to not load user profile by default and this causes the exception. In Azure App Settings, create an Application Setting called WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE and set it to 1. This will load the user profile.

https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/jaredjohnson/2015/12/18/resolving-cryptography-issues-with-the-dynamics-crm-sdk-in-azure-web-apps

Answer (score -1):

Got it working. I needed to use appBuilder.**SetDataProtectionProvider**

```
app.UseAppBuilder(appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.SetDataProtectionProvider(new MachineKeyProtectionProvider());

            appBuilder.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true
                };

                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });


        });
```

I use **katana extension methods** to bridge the IAppBuilder to IApplicationBuilder.
This allows your owin middleware to connect to asp.net core. It is important to use the **RunSignalr** method.

internal class MachineKeyProtectionProvider : IDataProtectionProvider
    {
        public IDataProtector Create(params string[] purposes)
        {
            return new MachineKeyDataProtector(purposes);
        }
    }

```
internal class MachineKeyDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purposes;

    public MachineKeyDataProtector(string[] purposes)
    {
        _purposes = purposes;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        //return MachineKey.Protect(userData, _purposes);
        return userData;
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        //return System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purposes);
        return protectedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very insecure. You can read up on how data protection is used to encrypt connection token here: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken. I think what you may be missing is a machine key.

Comment: @Pawel: I agree this is insecure. Forgot to tell this solution is not really fitted for production environments.